# Show that the language is undecidable

Tags: computability, formal-languages

I want to show that the language $H_\epsilon=\{x \mid M_x(\epsilon )\text{ halts } \}$ is undecidable, by reducing $H_0$ to that.

We have that $M_x$ is the Turing machine that is coded by $x$ and  $H_0$ is the restricted halting problem, $H_0=\{x\mid M_x(x)\text{ halts } \}$.

Suppose that $H_\epsilon$ is decidable. Then there is Turing machine that computes this language for every input. That means that it is also computed with input $x$, that means that $H_0$ is then also decidable. Contradiction.

Is this the correct idea for the proof?

Comment: I don't understand your proposed proof (what does "computes this language for every input" even mean?), and I'm mostly sure that you must be misunderstanding something. For a reduction, you're supposed to assume that you have an oracle that will determine membership in $H_\epsilon$ for you, and describe how you can use that oracle to decide whether an _arbiratry_ $x$ that your adversary selects is in $H_0$ or not.

Comment: I'm still not sure what $H_\epsilon$ is. Is it the halting problem or is it the specific problem of whether a Turing machine halts on the empty string $\epsilon$?

Comment: I mean that when $H_\epsilon$ is decidable, we have that there is a Turing machine that halts on any input. Is it wrong? @HenningMakholm

Comment: @MaryStar: I'm afraid it's _not even_ wrong. I'm not sure what "when $H_\epsilon$ is decidable" means -- what do you imagine can change such that $H_\epsilon$ would be decidable some of the time?

Comment: I mean that if we suppose that $H_\epsilon$ is decidable then there would be a Turing machine that halts on any input. @HenningMakholm

Comment: @MaryStar: This still sounds confused -- _of course_ there is a Turing machine that halts on every input; just let the starting state be a halting state. But (a) we don't need to assume anything about $H_\epsilon$ to know that, and (b) having a Turing machine that halts on everything doesn't help us decide $H_0$ anyway, so I still have trouble imagining even a _wrong_ argument you could have in mind.

Comment: Suppose that $x\in H_0$. We have to define a function $f$ such that $x\in H_0\Leftrightarrow f(x)\in H_\epsilon$, right? But how exactly can we define it? Could you give me a hint? @HenningMakholm

Comment: When you say "reducing $H_0$ to it" do you mean a Turing reduction or a many-one reduction? It seems from your previous comment that you want a many-one reduction. That is possible in this case. You can get the necessary function in this case very directly by using the S-m-n theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smn_theorem

Comment: At the same time, the $f$ is in the wrong place in your previous comment. $A$ is many-one reducible to $B$ is there is a computable function such that, for all $n$, $n \in A$ if and only if $f(n) \in B$. So you want to make an $f$ such that, for alL $n$, $n \in H_\epsilon$ if and only if $f(x) \in H_0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "many-one reduction" ? @CarlMummert